# I am missing my button

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to add a `SimpleButton`...

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{   
    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        var btn:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();      
        this.addChild(btn);
```

But it is nowhere to be found. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried setting the x/y for the button?

Comment: yes, i have :-) x= 10, y = 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SimpleButton needs DisplayObjects (Sprites, for instance) in its constructor. If you don't specify any, it will not have anything to show.

from the manual:

```
SimpleButton(upState:DisplayObject = null, overState:DisplayObject = null, downState:DisplayObject = null, hitTestState:DisplayObject = null)
```